# GetColumnName() in EF Core 6 returns property name not mapped column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF Core 6 (6.0.2) with SQL Server 2019 with the following entity:

```
public partial class MyEntity
{
        [Column("External_ExternalId")]
        public Guid? ExternalId { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to get the mapped column name (`External_ExternalId`) for the `ExternalId` property with the following code:

```
var entityType = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(MyEntity));
var property = entityType.GetProperties().Single(property => property.Name.Equals("ExternalId", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
var columnName = property.GetColumnName(StoreObjectIdentifier.Create(property.DeclaringEntityType, StoreObjectType.Table).GetValueOrDefault());
```

columnName is `ExternalId` instead of `External_ExternalId`.
How can I get the actual name of the table's column?
I tried `GetColumnBaseName()` but got the same result. Same if I configure the mapping with  the fluent API.

Comment: After playing with the code above a bit and restarting Visual Studio, the same snippet of code seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Because the column name is defined using a `[Column(...)]` attribute, you can get the desired outcome by looking for **`ColumnAttribute`** objects that are attached to the properties of the class, as follows:

```
public static void PrintValueOfColumnAttribute()
{
    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(MyEntity).GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in props)
    {
        foreach (var attr in prop.GetCustomAttributes(true))
        {
            if (attr is ColumnAttribute columnAttr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prop.Name + " -> " + columnAttr.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
ExternalId -> External_ExternalId
```

Comment: While this would be somehow a workaround, turns out that my environment (PC?, Visual Studio?) was acting up. Posted code works as intended, so there's no actual question to be answered.
My apologies, Peter, I don't know what the proper thing to do here is, I'd like to delete my question, but got a warning because there's already an answer. 
Would you mind deleting your answer to see if I can delete the q without warning?